# Unity VR game development: one Object that accepts other many objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, virtual-reality

I'm trying to develop a VR puzzle game. Like the pic below. Its name is Cubism.
[Cubism](https://youtu.be/D8ufYPkKK6E?t=17)

As you see here, I want to make the socket Object that can accept other objects at once.
[cubism socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbtlQ.png)

Can you give some advice to make that Grabbable Socket that can equip multiple Puzzle pieces at once like the Game??

I have tried with some complex objects that have socket ability but it doesn't work.
I thought the complex socket object will have multiple capable space in which the other puzzle object can enter.